# Moving data from windows application to web browser control

Tags: windows, web-applications, forms, cookies

I am trying to get data into a web application that runs in a web browser control.

My thought is to use a cookie.  Is it possible for the windows form to set a cookie variable that the web application can read and vice-versa?

If so, how?  I've done some googling but can't figure it out.

(Language: C#)

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible for both applications to see a common database or common service?

Comment: Hi Michael, yes, but they don't want to alter the database or pass via query string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the desktop application I do this:

> string test = "aaaaaaaaa";
>
> browser.Document.Cookie = "MyValue=" + test;

The web application inside the browser control is able to read it.

Cool.